# How I get different versions of browsers on windows 7

Tags: css, testing, browser, cross-browser

I am running windows 7 with these browsers :

- IE11
- Chrome 31.0.1650.63
- Firefox 25.0.1

For development of my application, I wanted test CSS code on different versions of browsers, and check how css styles are applied.

How can I get different versions of browsers for Chrome, IE, Firefox or is there any other solution to test?

Comment: [Get Browser Info Using Jquery](http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/2013/02/get-browser-info-using-jquery.html)

Answer (score 0):

if you want different versions of Ie on your system, then [IE Tester](http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) would be an option.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Internet Explorer. IE have an inbuilt development toolbar. Press F12 when IE is loaded and it will appear. This enables you to change browser mode for IE. Although I think they have changed this for IE11.